# Need help 301 htaccess RedirectMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need to do a trick directly after the file extension

`http://www.your-name.dk/Whatever-url.php-Whatever 301` --> `http://www.your-name.dk/Whatever.php`

I have try this one but did not Work

```
RedirectMatch permanent (.*).php.* htt*://www.your-name.dk/$1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htacess and then add this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-[^.]+\.php-\1$ $1.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Don't forget AllowOverride in httpd.conf. And this won't return 301 status, you should add R=301 to your answer

Comment: @Cyber-GuardEnterprise: Agreed, I completely missed `R=301` editing it now.